# Failed to load module script when trying to import a library

Tags: javascript, module, mime

> I was trying to import a library called three.js and I wrote this in my js file

`import * as THREE from './node_modules/three';`

> But when I oppened it in chrome with the live server in vscode, in the console., it showed this thing below

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`